# Where to store certificates used in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a bunch of authentication files and certificates I'm using with Django (mostly around push notifications). Where should I store these?

Is it inadvisable to store these in my private repo? If yes, how and where should I keep them?

Comment: Sensitive content, in general is not a good idea to store in repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You should not store your secret in version control software even when you use private repository, that's a big risk.

An option to keep them safe is using secret service such as [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).